# Profiling constant cache in CUDA

Tags: caching, cuda, profiling

How can I profile the constant cache for CUDA devices (compute capability 3.x). I am interested in the hit rate.

Thanks,

Bart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CUDA profiler (Nsight 4.0, Visual Profiler 6.0, nvprof 6.0, CUDA command line profiler 6.0) do not support profiling constant cache accesses.